# How to find the reduced angle of a triangle when the interior ones are given as multiples?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

The figure from below shows a quadrilateral. Find the angle labeled $x$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&8^{\circ}\\
2.&10^{\circ}\\
3.&15^{\circ}\\
4.&18^{\circ}\\
5.&5^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

The only identity which I can recall in quadrilaterals is that the sum of the interior angles add up to $360^{\circ}$. I attempted several ways to split the given angles but I couldn't find something useful. Can someone help me with this?. How can this problem be solved with congruence or similarity or what?.

It would be helpful that an answer could include some sort of drawing or image because it would help to identify the way to find the angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\angle ABD=\angle ADB=\theta$.

We have $\angle DAC=180^{\circ}-17x\Longrightarrow \angle DAB=180^{\circ}-12x\Longrightarrow \theta = 6x$

Therefore $\angle BDC=14x-6x=8x=\angle BCD\Longrightarrow \overline{BC}=\overline{BD}$

Since $\overline{AB}=\overline{AD}=\overline{BC}$, we have $\overline{AB}=\overline{AD}=\overline{BD}$, which implies that $\triangle ABD$ is an equilateral triangle.

Hence $\theta=60^{\circ}$, and since $\theta=6x$, we have $x=10^{\circ}$ as our final answer.[image]

Comment: We don't need $E$. Just observe that $\angle DAC = 180^\circ -17x$ and we have $\theta = 6x$.

Comment: @player3236 Oh damn you're right! My bad. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: @Student1058, you're on roll today! +3!

Comment: @cosmo5 Haha thanks. I'm in a really good mood today.

Comment: @Student1058 Other than the good mood I second that thanks to your patience on drawing with Geogebra it eased the delivery of the sketch. I think that the key here was to notice the existence of the equilateral triangle there. I ended up without noticing. Btw,I've recommend that you may use an increased thickness line for the equilateral triangle with a different color so it eases the understanding of your answer.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the advice!